how does Pandas actually perform indexing on custom based indices (integer and non-integer)
temp = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, 5), index=['John', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Kris'])
temp[-1]

this outputs to the value associated with 'Kris'
however, when I do this:
temp2 = pd.Series(['John', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Kris'], index=[5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
temp2[-1]

it throws a KeyError
I have a brief idea that Pandas performs indexing internally when the custom index is of non-integer type, but what I don't understand here, is how negative indexing works? does the -1 essentially mean that Pandas is referring to the custom index list and then getting the '-1'th or the last element, which is Kris, and then passes 'Kris' as a label to the index?
I do know that a single integer is treated as a label in indexing, so how does this work? and that too, only for custom indexes where the type is non-integer; what am I missing here?

Just be explicit, use temp2.iloc[-1]

Which version are you using? Indexing is something of a hybrid of the loc and iloc methods - and its changing. I am not up-to-date (2.1.0 with 2.2.2 being current) and I get the warning FutureWarning: Series.getitem treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use ser.iloc[pos]

version 2.0.3 in google colab. I appreciate the help with iloc for integer based indexing, but I'm very curious to know why Pandas show such behaviour, like what actually is happening behind the code?

This mixed type of indexing probably shouldn't exist and is definitely not reliable (it will actually be removed in future versions).
Be explicit, use iloc for positional indexing:
temp2.iloc[-1]

Output: 'Kris'
why does temp2[-1] fail?
If you have an integer index, you could have negative values:
temp3 = pd.Series(['John', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Alice', 'Kris'], index=[5, -1, 7, 8, 9])
temp3[-1] # 'Joe'


I understand the 'temp2[-1]', since it is not a label, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why did temp[-1] work in the first place.

It works because it's a convenience. In the early days of pandas, there were many methods for indexing some of which accepted ambiguous indices like this. IMO this should be removed and the indexing should be strict.

like @tdelaney (idk how to tag users in here) said, something of a hybrid between loc and iloc? this is interesting

I updated the answer, this "feature" is now deprecated and will be removed.

@dumaloo - Just guessing, but if the type is compatible with the index ("label" is a row index), pandas uses .loc, which is strictly index based. Otherwise, there is special case for integers to use .iloc which is position based. Pandas wanted Series to work with code that is normally written for python lists, but with an optional index, that had its share of problems.

this is actually cool, but can be confusing at first, until you get a hang of it.. eventually? anyways, i'm gonna stick with both inputs, iloc and loc. thanks! ^^
